# how to remove special characters from string in volt templates

Tags: phalcon, volt

[image]

Please can anyone help me on this issue? how to remove special characters from string

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filters available for Volt

https://docs.phalconphp.com/4.0/en/volt.html#filters

So your code becomes

```
{{ title | escape }}
```